# Can you detect moving between open tabs in different Windows?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Using background.js in a Chrome Extension can you detect the focus moving from one tab to another?

I'm talking about a very specific situation - not just using onactivated to detect that the user has clicked a different tab.

If I have two Chrome windows open (same user account), each with a different webpage showing, and the user simply clicks to bring one to the front (so you can scroll and read the page), the onactivated event does NOT fire. It only seems to fire if you move between tabs in a single window.

I can capture mousedown etc, but if you just click once to bring a window to the front these events don't fire either (a second click fires mousedown).

Seems a strange oversight...I would have thought onactivated would cover this scenario - the user, they've activated it.

In fact, onactivated doesn't fire when you click that second time. I guess it's specific to switching tabs in a single window.

Comment: Since the active tab doesn't change in neither window, chrome.tabs.onActivated isn't fired, which is correct. Listen to chrome.windows.onFocusChanged instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you...write it up as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.tabs.onActivated` fires when the active tab in a window changes [[docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated)], meaning it's per window so it won't fire unless the user switches to a different tab within that tab's window.

Solution: use `chrome.windows.onFocusChanged` that fires when a Chrome window is activated [[docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onCreated)].

> Reports chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE if all Chrome windows have lost focus. Note: On some Linux window managers, WINDOW_ID_NONE is always sent immediately preceding a switch from one Chrome window to another.

```js
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(windowId => {
  // do something
});
```

You can specify the type of windows to report:

```js
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(windowId => {
  // do something
}, {windowTypes: ['normal']});
```